# Angular firebase deploy on second hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I have 2 hosting in my project. I need to upload my application in other hosting. But in project lists its not showing other hosting option.

Steps i follow

1. `npm install -g firebase-tools`
2. `firebase login`
3. `firebase init`

then i select the project

4. and `firebase deploy`

but need to upload on second hosting

Comment: please [edit] your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.  what does "other hosting" mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your project using this command `firebase use <project_id>`

and you can set your default project in **.firebaserc**

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "<project_name>"
  }
}
```

You are looking for this

```
firebase target:apply hosting target-name resource-name
```

[Read more Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites)

Comment: I try it but in console look like is going to first hosting. hosting[puasda-e38c9]: beginning deploy... i change the default to puasda-dashboard. but its hosting in other project

Comment: thanks in this resource name is project name and target name is hosting ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are working with two different projects.  If you access those projects with the same Google account, you can add a second project to your local configuration with the `firebase use --add` command, as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#add_alias):

> **Add a project alias**
>
> When you select a Firebase project during project initialization, the
>   project is automatically assigned the alias of default. However, to
>   allow project-specific commands to run against a different Firebase
>   project but still use the same project directory, run the following
>   command from within your project directory:
>
> ```
> firebase use --add
> ```
>
> This command prompts you to select another Firebase project and assign
>   the project as alias. Alias assignments are written to a .firebaserc
>   file inside your project directory.

Then you can use that alias to [switch projects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#use_aliases).

> `firebase use project_id_or_alias` Directs all commands to run against the specified Firebase project. The CLI uses this project as the currently "active project".

Read more of the documentation for more details.

If you have to use different Google accounts for each project, you will have to log out and log back in with the CLI each time you want to change.

Comment: Thanks but not working with 2 different project i have 2 different hosting in one project .

Comment: Could you edit the question to more accurately describe the way you have your project set up, and what you've tried to do, based on what you've read in the documentation? https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites